# Debugging GWT from a Windows Form Widget using Super Dev Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, intellij-idea, gwt

We have a C# WinForms wrapper for a browser as part of an internal application.

Most of the examples of using GWT Super Dev Client Debugger involves a browser.

I'm curious to see if it's possible to enable client side breakpoints to get hit within intellij using the winforms widget.

Current Configuration:

- IDE IntelliJ 2022.1.3
- GWT Version  2.8
- Wrapper Version: .Net 4.0 with WinForms. (System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser)